# creating a "for loop" in a single line of code

Tags: r, loops

I've just started working with R/Rstudio, and I have made a simple for loop which looks at a dataset "Galaxies", takes Black holes with a mass greater than 9, and then divides their distance in light-years ("Distance") by 1000. I've now been asked how to perform this task in 1 line of code and I'm wondering what the best day to this was?

This is what I have managed so far:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(galaxies)){
if(galaxies$BlackHoleMass[i] > 9){
    print(galaxies[i,"Distance"]/1000)
    }
 }
```

I have tried this

`galaxies[galaxies$BlackHoleMass>=9,print(galaxies[Distance]/1000`

but I get the error: "unexpected symbol in:"

(Apologies, this is my first question on Stack Overflow so if I have left out/formatted something wrong let me know!)

Comment: Hi, I'm not the teacher but I guess the point of the exercise might be to say that making for loops in R is, most of the time, useless.
I guess writing galaxies$Distance[galaxies$BlackHoleMass>=9]/1000 is fine if you just wanna get the distances considered

Comment: You could also do it like this: `with(galaxies, Distance[which(BlackHoleMass > 9)]/1000)`.  The `with()` function basically attaches the `galaxies` data to the search path for everything inside the parentheses, meaning you don't have to use `galaxies$` in front of the variables.

Comment: Thank you guys! Both seemed to work!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to use a subset/filter (only select black holes with a mass > 9) and then divide the distance of them by 1000. Assuming its not necessary to print the result you could use this.

```
library(dplyr)
galaxies %>% filter(BlackHoleMass > 9) %>% mutate(Distance = Distance/1000)
```

But maybe the use of pipe functions is cheating ;)

Comment: Hi @Maarvd! Thanks for the response, I've tried running it but I seem to get the error:    
```Error in mutate(., Distance = Distance/1000) : 
  could not find function "mutate""```

Comment: Did you install the package "dplyr" (install.packages("dplyr") and loaded it using library(dplyr)? Mutate is a function of that package.